# Adding Key value to Vuex State Array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have an empty state like so and I am trying to add values to it in key value format using the mutation.

```
new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        comboBoxNewValues: []
    },
    mutations: {

        addComboBoxValues(state, _value) {
            console.log(_value);
            state.comboBoxNewValues[_value.input] = _value['value'];
        }
})
```

I call the mutation like this.

```
_this.$store.commit('addComboBoxValues', { input: 'foo', value: ['value': 1, 'name': 'bar']});
```

After mutation the state is still empty. What could be the problem?

Comment: Are you sure it is `_this` and not `this` ? 
Are you storing the vue component's `this` into `_this` ?

Comment: Yes that is _this only. The mutator call is inside a axios call and storing this inside _this

Comment: Where are you checking the state ? 
if it is vue dev tools, try refreshing it, sometimes it does not update when the state is updated. 
The above code should work.

Comment: Did it, it didnt work. I used dev tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

comboBoxNewValues is an array which doesn't have associative keys, you should make it an object. `comboBoxNewValues: {}`

Comment: Oh, that was so silly mistake. Thanks for the help.